# Can anyone help me how to get value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to javascript that why i don't know how to get value using javascript.

**Here is my PHP script**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<div class='loop'>";
    if($row['choice'] == 0){
        echo "<p>First Choice</p>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value='0' />";
    }
    elseif($row['choice'] == 1){
        echo "<p>Second Choice</p>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value='1' />";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='1' />This is A</p>
              <p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='2' />This is B</p>
              <p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='3' />This is C</p>";

        //content_a
        echo "<div id='content_a'>";
            echo "<p>First Choice</p>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value='0' />";
        echo "</div>";

        //content_b
        echo "<div id='content_b'>";
            echo "<p>Second Choice</p>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value='1' />";
        echo "</div>";

        //content_c
        echo "<div id='content_c'>";
            echo "<p>Third Choice</p>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value='2' />";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "<a style='text-decoration: none; color: #000000;' class='alert'
          href='#' onclick='return false;'>Alert</a>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

**Javascript**

```
//when click on alert button
$(".alert").bind('click', function(){
    var type = $(this).parents('.loop').find("#hidden").val();
    alert(type);
});

//when radio button change
$('input[name=content_type]').bind('change', function(){
    var n = $(this).val();
    switch(n)
        {
          case '1':
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_a').show(1000);
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_b').hide(1000);
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_c').hide(1000);
              break;
          case '2':
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_b').show(1000);
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_a').hide(1000);
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_c').hide(1000);
              break;
          case '3':
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_c').show(1000);
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_a').hide(1000);
              $(this).parents('.loop').find('#content_b').hide(1000);
              break;
        }
});
```

My javascript script above work only when ***choice == 0 and choice == 1*** (when I click alert button with ***choice == 0***, it will alert 0, and click alert button with ***choice == 1***, it will alert 1). But if ***choice == 2***, it didn't work at all, it alerts undefined. I want when ***choice == 3*** and user choose the radio button, it will do like below:

```
- if user choose **This is A** and click Alert button, it will alert 0
- if user choose **This is B** and click Alert button, it will alert 1
- if user choose **This is C** and click Alert button, it will alert 2
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thank in advance

Comment: create a live html demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's much better to post HTML, not PHP code that generates HTML (unless your question is about PHP of course).

Answer (score 2):

You have logic for

```
if($row['choice'] == 0){
```

and

```
elseif($row['choice'] == 1){
```

but not in the same manner if the choice is 2.

You also have three inputs with id='hidden.' Is it possible that the following line is finding the wrong hidden element?

```
var type = $(this).parents('.loop').find("#hidden").val();
```

A live example in a site like jsfiddle.net would help us tinker more easily.

Answer (score 0):

you are given same id's in the below code. id's need to given unique name.

```
echo "<div id='content_a'>";
            echo "<p>First Choice</p>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value='0' />";
        echo "</div>";

        //content_b
        echo "<div id='content_b'>";
            echo "<p>Second Choice</p>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value='1' />";
        echo "</div>";

        //content_c
        echo "<div id='content_c'>";
            echo "<p>Third Choice</p>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value='2' />";
        echo "</div>";
```